# Rotation Invariance of measure

Tags: measure-theory

i know that lebesgue measure is rotation invariant but can anyone please tell me that why $\sigma$ on $S^{n-1}$ is invariant under rotation where $$\sigma (E)=n\mu_n(E_1)$$ where $\mu_n$ is the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and $E_1=\{rx' : ~r\in (0,1] ~\And~x'\in E\}$ and $E\in \mathbb B(S^{n-1})$.

---

as i was able to think it may be due to dependency of $\sigma$ on $\mu_n$ and the property that $\mu_n$ is rotation invariant but i am not sure about my argument. Any type of help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing needed here is that if $\alpha$ is a rotation, then
$$(0,1]\cdot\alpha(E)\ =\ \alpha(\,(0,1]\cdot E\,)$$
where the notation $(0,1]\cdot E$ is used for $E_1$.